# Fetching multiple values from ui

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface

I'm planning to build an ui which has few fields like text boxes, dates etc. I need to allow users to add values to all these fields as many times as needed by them.
Ex:user fills all the data and submits the data and it shud be stored temporarily and all fields shud get cleared on ui, so user can fill up data again with new values.
Once all this is done user will hit submit to send all the collected data to backend as part of one api call. Could you guys help me to know how to implement this?

Comment: Always break down your issue so you can easier find existing answers. You want to 1) collect form data in an array 2) send a bunch of data to the server as JSON - two separate, unrelated problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output:

[image]

Here is an example about how you can do it:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [serverData, setServerData] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setServerData(serverData.concat({ name: name, number: number }));
    setName("");
    setNumber("");
    console.log(serverData);
  };

  const sendToServer = () => {
    console.log("server ko post request with following data...");
    console.log(serverData);
    setName("");
    setNumber("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
        <input value={number} onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)} />
        <button>add data</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={sendToServer}>Submit to server</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hjiz33?file=src/App.js) link of app.